# The file cannot be accessed in the docker container

Tags: docker, containers

I created the container with a docker image. And mount a directory into it. But then I found out that I forgot a directory A. I now copy this directory A to the mounted directory on the host, hoping to be able to access it in the container.
This directory A can be seen in the container. But it cannot be accessed.

```
root@6ab9b803ae14:~/chipyard/sims/verilator/workDir/unicore-toolchains/uc4-1.0.5-hard/bin# ls
unicore32-linux-addr2line  unicore32-linux-c++filt  unicore32-linux-gcc-4.4.2  unicore32-linux-gprof    unicore32-linux-objdump  unicore32-linux-strings
unicore32-linux-ar         unicore32-linux-cpp      unicore32-linux-gccbug     unicore32-linux-ld       unicore32-linux-ranlib   unicore32-linux-strip
unicore32-linux-as         unicore32-linux-g++      unicore32-linux-gcov       unicore32-linux-nm       unicore32-linux-readelf
unicore32-linux-c++        unicore32-linux-gcc      unicore32-linux-gfortran   unicore32-linux-objcopy  unicore32-linux-size
root@6ab9b803ae14:~/chipyard/sims/verilator/workDir/unicore-toolchains/uc4-1.0.5-hard/bin# ./unicore32-linux-gcc
bash: ./unicore32-linux-gcc: No such file or directory
root@6ab9b803ae14:~/chipyard/sims/verilator/workDir/unicore-toolchains/uc4-1.0.5-hard/bin#
```

[image]
Why is this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check `ldd` for dependencies (in container). If they are not available in your container it shows that error.
If you try to run a 32bit on a 64bit OS you'll need a lib for ldd depending your (Container-)OS.. e.g. `ia32-libs` or `lib32z1`

Should be something like this:

```
ldd x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2afbd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f68b7078000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f68b7276000)
```

If it shows `not found` you have to install that..

Comment: Thanks! I tried this command and added relevant information.

Comment: What says file .\unicore...

Comment: ./unicore...       will  appear "No such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry was on mobile device. I meant enter ```file ./unicore32-linux-gcc``` in host OS.